# Text in XML on to lines after XSLT

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have a something like this in my XML file

```
<ELEMENT attribute="Value of the attribute">Some text</ELEMENT>
```

The XSLT template is

```
<span>
    <p>
        <xsl:value-of select="@attribute"/>
    </p>
</span>
```

After being convert by some XSLT, I have this

```
<span>
    <p>
        Value of the attribute
    </P>
 </span>
```

But sometime, the value of the attribute is too long an I want to display it on two line.
How can I do that? Is it possible to put something in the value of the attribut to de a carriage return?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could add the newline entity `&#10;` to the attribute value. It will cause a line break at the desired position:

```
<ELEMENT attribute="Value of the&#10;attribute">Some text</ELEMENT>
```

That should lead to something like this:

```
<span>
  <p>
    Value of the 
attribute
  </p>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

the coded new line as the other answer says is your best option but note that this is almost entirely dependant on which XSL processor you use, even down to the version - ie, msxsl 3 and 4 will produce different output (3 will take a lot more lines).

It goes on the basis that your output will display the same in html whether you have a new line in it or not

The other option is to check the line length in your XSL and if it is too long, break it manually at the nearest space

Answer (score 0):

**Here is an XSLT 2.0 transformation that splits the words into two lines so that the first line doesn't exceed a predefined length**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:param name="pMaxLength" select="15"/>

 <xsl:template match="ELEMENT">
  <xsl:variable name="vWords" select="tokenize(@attribute, '\W+')"/>

  <xsl:variable name="vNumWords" select="count($vWords)"/>

  <xsl:variable name="vLastWordPos" select=
   "for $k in 1 to vNumWords
      return
         if(string-length(string-join($vWords[position() le $k],
                                      ' ')
                          )
            le $pMaxLength
         and
            string-length(string-join($vWords[position() le $k+1],
                                      ' ')
                          )
            gt $pMaxLength
            )
         then $k
         else ()
   "/>

   <xsl:variable name="vLastPos" select=
    "($vLastWordPos, $vNumWords)[1]"/>

      <span>
        <p>
         <xsl:value-of select=
         "string-join($vWords[position() lt $vLastPos], ' '),
          string-join($vWords[position() ge $vLastPos], ' ')
         "
         separator="&#xA;"/>
        </p>
       </span>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<ELEMENT attribute="Value of the attribute">Some text</ELEMENT>
```

**The wanted, correct result is prodiced:**

```
<span>
   <p>Value of the
attribute</p>
</span>
```

**Do note**: As the output is HTML, you probably would want to replace this in the above code:

```
  <span>
    <p>
     <xsl:value-of select=
     "string-join($vWords[position() lt $vLastPos], ' ')"/>
     <br />
      <xsl:value-of select=
              "string-join($vWords[position() ge $vLastPos], ' ')"/>
    </p>
   </span>
```